# Typescript: is short hand for union of undefined and string is optional property type?

Tags: typescript

I find it is weird, so can someone confirm either these two are the same.

```
interface TypeA {
 time: string | undefined;
}

interfaceTypeB {
 time?: string;
}
```

Comment: Yes they are not identical `string | undefined` means you need to explicitly set the property, for ? you can leave it unset and it means it is undefined. For me this is one of language fuckups, but maybe I dont get the reasoning of this difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are similar, but not identical. Try the following for example:

```
interface TypeA {
 time: string | undefined;
}

interface TypeB {
 time?: string;
}

const exampleA: TypeA = {}

const exampleB: TypeB = {}
```

`exampleA` will give an error, because it needs the undefined time to be explicit. Merely omitting the property does not suffice. `exampleB` gives no error.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=27#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECCyDeAUMmMALYQBcyAzmFKAObIA%20yAriACYQygRcA3IQC%20hQqEixEKDNgBCBYqQoB%20anQYhGwsYQQB7EHWQQAHnDKYANrmpzcyALwE9h42FMWrt%20fawQii74IkA)